# React Select - How to Implement React Select with "Load More" button in the footer to load five more address records

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am currently working on implementing a React Select component for address selection in my application. I want to incorporate a "Load More" button in the footer of the dropdown to dynamically load five more address records each time it is clicked.

Here's a simplified version of my existing code:

API Response:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": "6b136fef-f6bd-4f15-85c6-43f3567d5ad5",
            "address": "1-123 12 AV NW",
            "postalCode": "T2M0C4",
            "city": "CALGARY",
            "country": "CANADA",
            "province": "ALBERTA",
            "standardized": true,
            "duplicated": false,
            "addressDetailZoneCode": null
        },
        {
            "id": "5b0758e8-d9c4-466b-9167-c97733d50a86",
            "address": "1-123 13 AV NE",
            "postalCode": "T2E1B5",
            "city": "CALGARY",
            "country": "CANADA",
            "province": "ALBERTA",
            "standardized": true,
            "duplicated": false,
            "addressDetailZoneCode": null
        }
    ],
    "totalPages": 5,
    "last": false,
    "totalElements": 10,
    "size": 2,
    "number": 0,
    "sort": null,
    "numberOfElements": 2,
    "first": true
}
```

React Component declared as

```
<Select
                              theme='bootstrap3'
                              placeholder={i18n.t('search_for_address')}
                              onInputChange={this.searchAddress}
                              options={this.state.addressSelectorList}
                              value={this.state.addressValue}
                              onBlur={this.addressBlur}
                              isSearchable={true}
                              isClearable={true}
                            />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overriding the `Menu` component, basically adding your button at the end (after `children`). Then, when the user clicks the button you refresh your `options`.